# $addToSet, along with updating other fields?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am having trouble updating document in MongoDB that involves adding to list and updating some fields, using Pymongo.

To summarize, I would like to:

1. Add a value to the a list.
2. Update some fields.
3. Using a single update statement.

I have tried 2 methods, but both doesn't work:

```
key = {'username':'user1'}

user_detail = {
'name':{'first':'Marie', 'last':'Bender'},
'items':{'$addtoset':{'cars':'BMW'}}
}

user_detail2 = {
'name':{'first':'Marie', 'last':'Bender'},
'$addtoset':{'items.cars':'BMW'}    
}

mongo_collection.update(key, user_detail, upsert=True)
mongo_collection.update(key, user_detail2, upsert=True)
```

error message: dollar ($) prefixed field '$addToSet' in '$addToSet' is not valid for storage.

My intended outcome:

Before:

```
{
   'username':'user1',
   'item': {'cars':['Merc','Ferrari'],'house':1}
}
```

Intended After:

```
{
   'username':'user1',
   'name': {'first':'Marie', 'last':'Bender'},
   'item': {'cars':['Merc','Ferrari','BMW'],'house':1}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second attempt is closer, but you need to use the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) operator to set the value of `name`:

```
user_detail2 = {
    '$set': {'name': {'first': 'Marie', 'last': 'Bender'}},
    '$addtoset': {'items.cars': 'BMW'}    
}
```